# MongoDB\Driver\Manager Queries

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm using mongodb driver to connect to mongodb through PHP. I was unable to connect to mongodb using mongoClient().

Versions of my php and mongodb

php --version output
[image: 1]
mongo --version output
[image: 2]

so, I tried to connect it through mongodb driver. Here's the code...

```
$connection = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$bulk->insert(["number"=>$Number, "created"=>time()]);
$connection-> executeBulkWrite("dbName.collectionName", $bulk);
```

This is working fine to insert the data to mongodb.

Now, I want to get the no. of rows from a collection in database but unable to find any solution.

I tried this code for retrieving data from mongodb:

```
try {
    $connection = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    $filter = ["number"=> $Number];
    $query_mongo = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter);
    $mongoResult = $connection->executeQuery("dbName.collectionName", $query_mongo);
    $result = current($mongoResult->toArray());
    var_dump($result);
    } catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {
      $filename = basename(__FILE__);
      echo "The $filename script has experienced an error.\n"; 
      echo "It failed with the following exception:\n";
      echo "Exception:", $e->getMessage(), "\n";
      echo "In file:", $e->getFile(), "\n";
      echo "On line:", $e->getLine(), "\n";
    }
```

But I'm getting this error in browser console...

```
parsererror,SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 0,object(stdClass)#26 (3) {
  ["_id"]=>
  object(MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID)#25 (1) {
    ["oid"]=>
    string(24) "587c6e37e2d11616411c90a2"
  }
  ["number"]=>
  string(10) "123456"
  ["created"]=>
  int(1484549687)
}
```

Q1. can I get rid of this Mongodb\Driver\Manager and use the old mongoClient and How?

Q2. I want to get no. of rows in the table. How can i do that using this Driver\Manager?

Q3. Any solution to the given error?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I'm guessing you're calling your script through ajax which expects the response to be json? In that case, it's your `var_dump($result);` that gives you that parse error in the console, since (var_dump()) doesn't return json.

Comment: Regarding the mongoClient extension, it's deprecated, so why do you want to use that? http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php. The mongodb-driver is what is replacing it so, stick to that one.

Comment: yes, actually i'm not familiar with php that much but some how i had to work around it. Yes the above code is called through ajax and data type is json.

Comment: If you want to output json-data instead, try with: `echo json_encode($result);` instead of your `var_dump()`. Regarding the mongodb-driver, stick to the non-deprecated version that you now use and works.

Comment: now it is giving me this error: ` parsererror,SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 93,{"_id":{"$oid":"587c6e37e2d11616411c90a2"},"number":"123456","created":1484549687} `

Comment: Please show us your javascript (which makes the ajax-call). Add it to your question.

Comment: `$.ajax({url: '/wifi/login.php?action=verifyOTP',type:'POST',dataType:'json',data: data,success: function(response){console.log(response);if(response.message=='NUMBER VERIFIED SUCCESSFULLY'){window.location = '/wifi/index_social.php';},error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, ex) {console.log(textStatus + "," + ex + "," + jqXHR.responseText);}});`

Comment: Please add it, formatted, to your question instead of in a comment. Looking what you've posted, it contains mismatching `{}`-characters. (you don't close `}` the success callback before the `error:`-callback.).

Comment: any idea how to count the no. of rows.

Comment: Have you tried the [MongoCollection::count()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.count.php) method?

Comment: the prob solved yet or not?